In Laravel, how can I display a custom error message if any of the password complexity criteria is not met?
I am working on a blogging application in Laravel 8.
I have used the standard procedure Laravel 8 provides to ensure the password meets the complexity criteria:
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $rules = [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'confirmed', Password::min(6)->mixedCase()->letters()->numbers()->symbols()],
        'password_confirmation' => ['required', 'same:password'],
        'accept' => ['accepted'],
    ];

    $messages = [
        'first_name.required' => 'The "First name" field is required',
        'last_name.required' => 'The "Last name" field is required',
        'email.required' => 'Please provide a valid email address',
        'email.email' => 'The email address you provided is not valid',
        'email.unique' => 'The email address you provided is already in use',
        'password.required' => 'A password is required',
        'password.mixedcase' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
        'password.letters' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
        'password.numbers' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
        'password.symbol' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
        'accept.required' => 'You must accept the Terms & conditions of service'
    ];
    
    return Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
}

The intention is to show the (validation) error message "Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol" if any of the complexity criteria is not met.
I would love to be able to "merge" all complexity criteria into one message. Instead of:
'password.mixedcase' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
'password.letters' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
'password.numbers' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol',
'password.symbol' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol'

I want to be able to use something like:
'password.isComplex' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol'

But the expected thing does not happen. Instead, the standard messages are displayed, one for each failed criterion.
UPDATE
Using
'password.required' => 'your password required message here',
'password.*' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol'

does not work.
What is my mistake?

Have you tried using "bail"?

Why don't you only use 'password.required', but then with your specific message?

@KIKOSoftware I want to be able to "merge" all complexity criteria into one message.

@Robert What is "bail"?

Did you try
'password.required' => 'your password required message here',
'password.*' => 'Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol'


I did that and the message "Include uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number and one symbol" is displayed for any password-related invalidity, even if there is no password at all provided. Not OK. :(

Check the updated answer

The solution does not account for Password::min(6).

You could try using :
'password' => ['required', Password::defaults()]

And then add a message for required and one for defaults like you did in the above example.
Maybe this link in the docs can help:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#defining-default-password-rules
You would have a single rule defaults so just one message.
